# Bar plot popup on map when polygon is clicked not working large SQL Server database queries

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, shiny, leaflet

I am making a dashboard in R shiny. What I need to do is find locations that meet a criteria (by SQL Server query on a large database).  I need to plot the data that relates to each of those locations in a separate bar plot that pops up when the location is clicked on a map.  UPDATE NOTE: I've tried 2 attempts: Second set of code and error below first.

I keep some output - it looks like this:

A tibble: 16 x 2
Rowwise:

| location | plots |
| --- | --- |
| chr | list |
| 101502 | gg |
| 4101511 | gg |

etc (note : the result in location column is the expected names of locations)

And an error message like this:

> Warning in file(what, "rb") :
> cannot open file '/tmp/Rtmpu0mwwl/filef4e3a1ee7acec.png': No such file or directory
> Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
> [No stack trace available]

So it looks like it is complaining about the way I'm trying to generate the bar plots
There will be a lot of bars - is that an inherent problem? I could potentially make a table, order by largest sumc and use head if that is a design issue.
(in the unlikely case: Is there a way to tell ggplot directly  to order and only to plot the top 5 sumc?)

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
    plots <- reactive ({ 
    #this comes from a selectize in the ui 
    req(input$hc)
    hcname <- input$hc
    con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                     Server = DBServer, Database = "x", UID = DBUser,
                     PWD = DBPassword)
    
    #query db to get a list of location names to make a second query
    df_q1 <-  dbGetQuery(... WHERE table.something = hcname ))
    list_from_q1 <- df_q1$location
    #second query
    df_q2 <- dbGetQuery(.... WHERE paste(list_from_q1, collapse=" OR location ="))

    
    # group, get a sum 
    df_q2_summary = df_q2 %>% group_by(location, b) %>% summarise(location, b, sumc = sum(c))

    #I want to create a different bar plot for each location that you can click on in the map
    plots <- df_q2_summary %>% group_by(location) %>% do(plots = ggplot(data = .) + aes(x = b, y = sumc) + geom_bar(stat= "identity")+ ggtitle(unique(.$location)))
    })    
  
    
    df_q1_geom <- reactive ({
      req(input$hc)
      hcname <- input$hc
      con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                       Server = DBServer, Database = "x", UID = DBUser,
                       PWD = DBPassword)
      
      #this is the same query as Query 1 in plots
      df_q1 <-  dbGetQuery(... WHERE table.something = hcname)
      
      #inner join the locations of interest to a much spatial polygons data frame 
      df_q1_geom <- inner_join(shapefile.spdf, df_q1, by = "location")

    }) 

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>% 
        addPolygons(data = df_q1_geom(), popup = popupGraph(plots()), weight = 1.5, color = "light-blue", fillColor = "light-blue") %>%

      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap, options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.25))
  })
  
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can't call a function from within popupGraphs (would be nice if I could ;-)). So, instead of generating all of the plots as being a subset of locations as a result of being reactive, I've instead generated every possible plot for every location, not just a subset of locations that results from the reactive part.  It's thousands of plots but it worked (slowly).

I'd love a faster way.